# MS D365: Update same record in a Post-Operation Create plugin

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

Can I call an Update on the same record in a Post-Operation Create message plugin? It being Post-Operation it shouldn't be a problem in my opinion, but I keep getting an error "record with (..) GUID does not exist", even though it's a correct GUID and so it should be written into the DB already.

Comment: Yes, you can call an update on the record you just created in post create, although this is unusual.